# Amazon S3 Command Line Copy all objects to themselves setting Cache control

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an Amazon S3 bucket with about 300K objects in it and need to set the Cache-control header on all of them. Unfortunately it seems like the only way to do this, besides one at a time, is by copying the objects to themselves and setting the cache control header that way:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Is the documentation for the Amazon S3 CLI copy command but I have been unsuccessful setting the cache control header using it. Does anyone have an example command that would work for this. I am trying to set cache-control to max-age=1814400

Some background material:

- [Set cache-control for entire S3 bucket automatically (using bucket policies?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435334/set-cache-control-for-entire-s3-bucket-automatically-using-bucket-policies)
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=567440

Answer (score 10):

**By default, aws-cli only copies a file's current metadata, EVEN IF YOU SPECIFY NEW METADATA.**

To use the metadata that is specified on the command line, you need to add the '--metadata-directive REPLACE' flag.  Here are some examples.

*For a single file*

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/file.txt s3://mybucket/file.txt --metadata-directive REPLACE \
--expires 2100-01-01T00:00:00Z --acl public-read --cache-control max-age=2592000,public
```

*For an entire bucket:*

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket/ --recursive --metadata-directive REPLACE \
--expires 2100-01-01T00:00:00Z --acl public-read --cache-control max-age=2592000,public
```

A little gotcha I found, if you only want to apply it to a specific file type, you need to exclude all the files, then include the ones you want.

*Only jpgs and pngs*

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket/ --exclude "*" --include "*.jpg" --include "*.png" \
--recursive --metadata-directive REPLACE --expires 2100-01-01T00:00:00Z --acl public-read \
--cache-control max-age=2592000,public
```

Here are some links to the manual if you need more info:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#options

Comment: `REPLACE` makes problems: adding 'Cache-Control' now works, but this solution also breaks the 'ContentType' setting, changing it from existing, e.g. `image/png` to `binary/octet-stream`.

Comment: @geekQ are you saying that by adding cache-control, it changes the 'ContectType' setting?  Does it work if you specify 'ContentType' using the --content-type flag?  The way the docs read, aws is guessing the content type, are your extentions '*.png'?