# How can I read the metadata for every item in an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can set `Cache-Control` metadata on every item in an S3 bucket using the following command (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29280730/200783)):

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket s3://mybucket --recursive --metadata-directive REPLACE \
--cache-control max-age=86400
```

Is there a way to *read* the `Cache-Control` metadata for every item in a bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bash one-liner should work (but it is very slow since it sends separate request for each object):

```
IFS=$'\n'; for object in `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket-name --recursive | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4-`; do echo $object `aws s3api head-object --bucket my-bucket-name --key $object --query CacheControl` ; done
```

Comment: Thanks for this - as you say, it works but is quite slow. Also, for use with Cygwin, I had to set `IFS=$'\r\n'`.

Comment: I also swapped the "columns" of the output to improve alignment. The command I ended up using was `IFS=$'\r\n'; for object in \`aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket-name --recursive | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4-\`; do echo \`aws s3api head-object --bucket my-bucket-name --key $object --query CacheControl\` $object ; done`.