# Getting AWS S3 object metadata quickly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

This question [How can I read the metadata for every item in an S3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254895/how-can-i-read-the-metadata-for-every-item-in-an-s3-bucket) deals with the way how to get metadata for an object on AWS S3, however the process is painfully slow. Even if I use "boto3" I get to roughly 50 objects metadata in 7 seconds. Is there any reliable alternative? I only need data for one directory which can however contain few thousands objects. As last resort I was thinking about getting only newest object`s metadata but for that I would need metadata first I guess :)

Comment: You can either run python multithreaded or use nodejs that will speed up the process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind only getting the information once per day, you can use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html):

> **Amazon S3 inventory** provides comma-separated values (CSV) or Apache optimized row columnar (ORC) output files that list your objects **and their corresponding metadata** on a daily or weekly basis for an S3 bucket or a shared prefix (that is, objects that have names that begin with a common string).

If you need the information updated more often, you could configure an **Event** on the bucket that triggers an **AWS Lambda function** when a new object is created. The Lambda function could then store the information in a database for future reference. Of course, you'd have to write this code yourself.

Comment: Very interesting! Did not know about this. However I need it more frequently. Looks like most viable option would be threading. Thanks anyway...

Comment: You could also configure an Event on the bucket that triggers an AWS Lambda function when a new object is created. The Lambda function could then store the information in a database for future reference.

Comment: That looks like really good idea. I will study something about it and give it a try. Just wondering am I right in assuming I will be again calling same code (boto3) but from lambda? I am sure it will be faster in regards of connection but will it help speaking about requests? Or I can do some interesting magic between lambda and S3?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Yes, you can run Python/boto3 code in Lambda that can call AWS services. It can be triggered whenever a new object is created in the S3 bucket and it will be given the name & bucket of the incoming object.

Comment: No worries, I already seen some nice examples using Futures. Please add also the "lambda" way to your answer and I will accept it. Thanks for your time...