# Adding meta-data to a folder in amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, directory, cache-control

I can set 'Cache-Control'(meta data) of a particular file and a particular bucket in amazon S3.

But I want that `Cache-Control` to be set for every file in a particular folder(not the entire bucket, but only folder).

Also when I upload a new file in that particular folder, `Cache-Control` header gets automatically set for the new file.
I have followed [this](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-set-cache-control-header-for-s3-object.html) and [S3 Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingtheMetadataofanObject.html).

Is there any way by which this can be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set cache-control for entire S3 bucket automatically (using bucket policies?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435334/set-cache-control-for-entire-s3-bucket-automatically-using-bucket-policies)

Comment: @Joe I want changes for the entire folder, not the enitre bucket, but the entire folder.

Comment: HI @FreeFly any news about that?

Answer (score 3):

Based on another question's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435334/set-cache-control-for-entire-s3-bucket-automatically-using-bucket-policies) I found that with this [tool](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd) we can run a recursive for all files in a particular folder, but this won't be applied for the new files.

steps:

`git clone https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd`

`Run s3cmd --configure`

(You will be asked for the two keys - copy and paste them from your confirmation email or from your Amazon account page. Be careful when copying them! They are case sensitive and must be entered accurately or you'll keep getting errors about invalid signatures or similar. Remember to add s3:ListAllMyBuckets permissions to the keys or you will get an AccessDenied error while testing access.)

`./s3cmd --recursive modify --add-header="Cache-Control:public ,max-age= 31536000" s3://your_bucket_name/`

Answer (score 1):

@FreeFly

It seems like with the new updates to the S3 console UI, there is now an option to add metadata on a directory, and doing so will recursively apply metadata to each object within that directory.

Go to

1. Your Bucket
2. Check `object` (can be a directory)
3. Click on Select and from the dropdown menu select Edit metadata
4. then select Add metadata and enter metadata
5. Click on Edit Metadata.
   and this should recursively apply metadata to all objects inside current directory.