# How to achieve complex static file caching on AWS S3 objects (CreateReactApp build outputs)?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, cache-control

So, I have a React app hosted on a AWS S3 bucket (It also has a CloudFront distribution before it). Using a GitHub Actions workflow, I deploy my build output on S3 with [aws-cli s3 sync command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html):

```sh
aws s3 sync build s3://mybucket --delete --acl public-read
```

Now, I want to perform **static file caching** with the denoted starting configuration in the [CreateReactApp docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/#static-file-caching):

- `Cache-Control: max-age=31536000` for `build/static` assets,
- `Cache-Control: no-cache` for everything else (to ensure the browser will always check for an updated index.html file)

#### Question

How can I achieve applying such conditional configuration on S3 objects based on the file/folder paths?

#### What I thought/tried so far

- First I thought it could be done with a setting on the S3 bucket. But after some searching, now, my understanding is that there is no such setting on the bucket itself (at least, answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501465/how-to-add-cache-control-in-aws-s3) propose none).
- Then, I headed to `--cache-control` flag of [aws cli s3 sync docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html), but not did I find a direct, one-liner way of applying different cache controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done very simply with no configuration on the S3 side, as you're using CloudFront first this would be controlled in the behaviours.

You can define multiple [behaviours](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesCacheBehavior) which are matched based on path patterns. In CloudFront this would display as if you have multiple origins but both could go to the same S3 bucket.

You would have a path pattern of `build/static` for which you set the caching max age for all objects. Then for the default behaviour you would disable caching of objects.

[This article](https://medium.com/tensult/cloudfront-dynamic-caching-multiple-cache-behaviors-8b8bfb5393b3) has a basic demonstration for setting it up.

Comment: Funny I skipped CloudFront for a deeper solution as its TTL can be [overridden](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior-maxttl) by the resources. However, as you suggest, it may end up being the most proper solution. Gonna try and appreciate further.

Comment: Sure, I just think might end up being the simplest solution :)

Comment: Now, I applied CloudFront TTLs, and a PWA update on it: [Lighthouse scoring](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lighthouse-pwa-analysis-tool) still suggests the static content to be cached: Apparently, CloudFront does not add Cache-Control headers even if applies caching. Anyways, I don't know if Lighthouse or CloudFront to face the issue.

Comment: So the objects being cached are not returning cache headers?

Comment: Apparently so. I have a cache behavior added for `static/*` and fetching an object from `static` folder, does not respond with a `Cache-Control` header. But, instead, it is conveyed with rather a custom header like `x-cache: Hit from cloudfront`. This post also ends up with the idea of CF not setting `Cache-Control` header: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56187791/4636715

Answer (score 8):

Here’s what I use:

```
aws s3 sync build s3://bucket \
  --metadata-directive REPLACE \
  --cache-control max-age=86400 \
  --exclude index.html --exclude 'static/*' \
  --delete
aws s3 sync build/static s3://bucket/static \
  --metadata-directive REPLACE \
  --cache-control max-age=31536000,immutable \
  --size-only
aws s3 cp build/index.html s3://bucket \
  --metadata-directive REPLACE \
  --cache-control no-cache
```

Thus the public folder and misc other files are served with instruction to cache for 24 hours, `index.html` is served with instruction to never cache and the static folder is served with instruction to cache a year *and* with the `immutable` flag which supposedly can be a real boon for reloads [1].

Additionally we do *not* prune the static folder of old assets which means any browser out there that insists on using a stale build will still get those files. Which seems probably the correct choice rather than 404ing and being broken.

CloudFront will use these headers for its own cache *and* send them out to the browser.

[1]
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/01/using-immutable-caching-to-speed-up-the-web/