# Is there an option to add Cache-control TTL in S3 bucket (Cloudfront)?

Tags: amazon-s3, caching, yii2, amazon-cloudfront, cache-control

I'm publishing Yii2 Assets to S3 bucket cloudfront CDN, mannually there is an option to add Cache-control expiry (TTL). Seeking for an option to automate publish assets with Cache-control header in s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

cache-control can be added to S3 objects using both ways, while making PUTobject or updating the existing object metadata.

See the below thread:

[S3 cache-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435334/set-cache-control-for-entire-s3-bucket-automatically-using-bucket-policies)