# How do I change which index.html file my website loads when it's hosted on AWS Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I registered a domain with AWS Route 53 awhile ago and somehow included an index.html file (not through S3).  I don't remember how I did this, but the index.html is an outdated version of my website.  In the meantime, I have created a new index.html that I want to use for my website, and it is located in an S3 that I have configured to host a static website and connected to my Route 53 domain.  When I look at the endpoint of my S3 bucket, the website loads as I would expect, but when I navigate to my domain name, the old index.html site loads.  I have tried other browsers and cleared the cache without success.

These are the records that I currently have included in my domain: [Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpLJb.png)

I think one of those might be routing traffic to the original index.html?

How did I include the original index.html file when I created the domain, and how to change it to use the S3 bucket instead?  This is the first website I've hosted with AWS and am just learning, but I've scoured the tutorials and can't find anything about fixing an old html file in Route 53.

Comment: Test with a new browser or from a different machine or otherwise ensure that you're not seeing cached content. And check the instructions for [Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

Comment: " somehow included an index.html" - how you can include index.html in route53? Can you clarify exactly what did you do?

Comment: seems to be cache problem. clear browser cache and try, dns propagation may take some time also, your isp may cache the old file.

Comment: With Route 53 you cannot specify the index.hml - it is just a DNS service. If you are pointing directly to a S3 bucket with static content using Route 53 check the Route 53 domain name and the bucket with the same name and then the index file inside that bucket is correct. Also like @jarmod has suggested, maybe the index.html is cached on the browser side - try to load the site using a browser that you have not used be for to access the site or if you are happy to clear the cache for your specific URL then that might also help.

Comment: @Marcin I don't remember how I included the index.html in the original domain creation.  Could I have linked a github repository?  I did it over a month ago and it was my first time, so I just don't remember how I did it.

Comment: @TobievanderMerwe I'm fairly certain my S3 bucket is configured correctly to route traffic from my domain to the site I have in the bucket.  I cleared the cache but it's still loading the old index.html.

Comment: @SubhashisPandey I cleared the cache and tried a different browser without success.

Comment: @SubhashisPandey. If you are behind a proxy server then the proxy server can also cache the files - in that case try to connect from a network that are not behind a proxy. If you are not behid a proxy then look at this article and try to set the caching headers on the file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435334/set-cache-control-for-entire-s3-bucket-automatically-using-bucket-policies.

Comment: @TobievanderMerwe Thank you for responding.  The old index.html (the one that comes up when I navigate to my domain) isn't in an S3 bucket.  The only non-local place that it exists is github, unless something about setting up the domain asked me to upload it somewhere related to Route 53 that I don't remember.  I looked into routing traffic to a github, but everything I found about hosting a github page on a personal domain involved changing the domain in the page settings in the repo, and I didn't do that.