# Set cache control when copying files using s3p

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, s3p

I use [`s3p`](https://github.com/generalui/s3p) to deal with large number of files on [Amazon s3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/). I would like to set cache-control for the files I have copied. I tried:

```
s3p cp --bucket my-bucket --to-bucket my-bucket --cache-control max-age=31536000,private --prefix path/to/copy/src/ --to-prefix path/to/copy/dst/
```

This did not add cache control to the files in `s3://my-bucket/path/to/copy/dst/`. [Here I read about aws-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29280730/8565438):

> **NOTE: By default, aws-cli only copies a file's current metadata, EVEN IF YOU SPECIFY NEW METADATA.**

So, I try:

```
s3p cp --bucket my-bucket --to-bucket my-bucket --cache-control max-age=31536000,private --metadata-directive REPLACE --prefix path/to/copy/src/ --to-prefix path/to/copy/dst/
```

This command doesn't return any error either, but my cache control is not set in `s3://my-bucket/path/to/copy/dst/`

How can I use `s3p cp` and set cache-control of the destination?