# How can I generate the "AWS Authentication String" to send a POST to CloudFront from iOS?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I want to use the CloudFront API to POST an invalidation request (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/CreateInvalidation.html).

The request should look like this:

```
POST /2012-07-01/distribution/distribution ID/invalidation HTTP/1.0
Host: cloudfront.amazonaws.com
Authorization: AWS authentication string
Content-Type: text/xml
Other required headers

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InvalidationBatch xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-07-01/">
  <Paths>
    <Quantity>number of objects to invalidate</Quantity>
    <Items>
     <Path>/path to object to invalidate</Path>
    </Items>
  </Paths>
  <CallerReference>unique identifier for this invalidation batch</CallerReference>
</InvalidationBatch>
```

**What's the best way to generate the "AWS authentication string" from my iPhone app?**

This link describes how to create the string, but it seems overly complicated: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RESTAuthentication.html

I have access to my PEM file if that helps at all.

Comment: Oh dear - you waited a very long time and no reply - I also need to make an AWS authentication string for a distribution request... (in my case GET and POST ... copying a distribution). Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see it it in the [AWS iOS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/) . Sounds like it might [not be available just yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20291275/462002). Which is odd since other libraries, like Ruby's [fog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598533/462002) and [aws-cloudfront](https://github.com/iltempo/aws-cloudfront),  seem to have ways.