# Update cloudfront configuration using awscli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

I would like to edit/update my CloudFront distribution with awscli.

I'm using latest cli version:

`aws-cli/1.11.56 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.4.0 botocore/1.5.19`

To use cloudfront features in awscli you need to add this to your aws config file:

```
[preview]
cloudfront = true
```

I'm getting config of the distribution that I'd like to modify:

`aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id FOO_BAR_ID > cf_config.json`

Looks like it worked as expected. Config looks ok for me. Now I'm trying to reconfigure my CF distribution with the same config.

`aws cloudfront update-distribution --distribution-config file://cf_config.json --id FOO_BAR_ID`

and I'm getting:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "CallerReference"
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "Origins"
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "DefaultCacheBehavior"
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "Comment"
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "Enabled"
Unknown parameter in DistributionConfig: "ETag", must be one of: CallerReference, Aliases, DefaultRootObject, Origins, DefaultCacheBehavior, CacheBehaviors, CustomErrorResponses, Comment, Logging, PriceClass, Enabled, ViewerCertificate, Restrictions, WebACLId, HttpVersion, IsIPV6Enabled
Unknown parameter in DistributionConfig: "DistributionConfig", must be one of: CallerReference, Aliases, DefaultRootObject, Origins, DefaultCacheBehavior, CacheBehaviors, CustomErrorResponses, Comment, Logging, PriceClass, Enabled, ViewerCertificate, Restrictions, WebACLId, HttpVersion, IsIPV6Enabled
```

What is the right way to reconfigure CF using awscli?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to edit cf_config.json before using it with `update-distribution` and remove

```
{
    "ETag": "ETag_Value",
    "DistributionConfig":
```

from the beginning of the file and last

```
}
```

from the end of file.

Then use this command with the right `id` and `ETag` value that was removed from `cf_config.json`

```
aws cloudfront update-distribution --distribution-config file://cf_config.json --id FOO_BAR_ID --if-match ETag_Value
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to do all of this within one bash script ?

Comment: @KeshavKumaresan, if you install jq `apt install jq`, then you can just get the body of the request like this `/root/.local/bin/aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id <Your CloudFront ID> | jq .DistributionConfig`

Comment: Hi, can you show me the content of your `cf_config.json`

Comment: @KeshavKumaresan read my answer above for the full bash script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66960593

Answer (score 27):

@usterk's answer is correct, but it took me another 3 hours to get to the script that I needed.  Here, I am sharing it.

## My case: CI/CD using S3/CloudFront with manual artifact versioning

I am hosting a static website (SSG) in S3, and I want it to be served by CloudFront.  The website gets frequent updates in terms of its code (not just the content) and I want to store all the versions of the website in S3 (just like all the artifacts or docker images) and update CloudFront to point to a new version, right after a new version is pushed to S3.

I know that there is "file versioning" in S3, but this old-school format for keeping all versions of the assets helps with analyzing the assets as well as easy roll-backs.

#### My configs

- After building the assets (JS, CSS, etc), the new files are uploaded to S3 in a folder like `s3://<mybucket-name>/artifacts/<version-id>`
- In CloudFront I have a **Distribution** for `www` website. Route53 for `www.domain.com` is pointing to it.
- In that **Distribution** I have several **Origins** (e.g. one to send `/api` path to ELB.)
- The **Origin** that matter here is `www` which has its `OriginPath` pointing to `/artifacts/<version-id>`.

## Workflow

- After S3 sync is done via AWS CLI, I need to **update CloudFront's configs** for that www Origin's OriginPath value to point to the new path in S3.
- I also need to initiate an **invalidation** on the Distribution so CloudFront picks up the new files internally (between S3 and it)

### The Task

As @usterk and @BrianLeishman pointed out, the only CLI command for this job is `update-distribution` which [per the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html), requires the **ENTIRE CONFIGURATION** of the distribution to **REPLACE** it. So, there is no command to partially update just one field in the config.

To achieve this, one must first get the current distribution-config, then extract the "DistributionConfig" component, then update the fields it takes, and finally, put it back in the proper format with a proper verification token.

Note that what the "update" command needs is a "subset" of what "get" gives back.  So parsing JSON via `jq` is inevitable.

### The Bash Script

The following script that I came up with, does the job for me:

```sh
# 0) You need to set the followings for your case
CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID="EABCDEF12345ABCD"
NEW_ORIGIN_PATH="/art/0.0.9"
CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_ID="E1A2B3C4D5E6F"

DIST_CONFIG_OLD_FILENAME="dist-config.json" # a temp file, which will be removed later
DIST_CONFIG_NEW_FILENAME="dist-config2.json" # a temp file, which will be removed later

# 1) Get the current config, entirely, and put it in a file
aws cloudfront get-distribution --id $CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID > $DIST_CONFIG_OLD_FILENAME

# 2) Extract the Etag which we need this later for update
Etag=`cat $DIST_CONFIG_OLD_FILENAME | jq '.ETag' | tr -d \"`

# 3) Modify the config as wished, for me I used `jq` extensively to update the "OriginPath" of the desired "originId"
cat $DIST_CONFIG_OLD_FILENAME | jq \
    --arg targetOriginId $CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_ID \
    --arg newOriginPath $NEW_ORIGIN_PATH \
    '.Distribution.DistributionConfig | .Origins.Items = (.Origins.Items | map(if (.Id == $targetOriginId) then (.OriginPath = $newOriginPath) else . end))' \
    > $DIST_CONFIG_NEW_FILENAME

# 4) Update the distribution with the new file
aws cloudfront update-distribution --id $CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID \
    --distribution-config "file://${DIST_CONFIG_NEW_FILENAME}" \
    --if-match $Etag \
    > /dev/null

# 5) Invalidate the distribution to pick up the changes
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths "/*"

# 6) Clean up
rm -f $DIST_CONFIG_OLD_FILENAME $DIST_CONFIG_NEW_FILENAME
```

### Final Note: IAM Access

The user that performs these needs IAM access to the Get, Invalidate, and Update actions on the Distribution in CloudFront.  Here is the Policy that gives that:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudfront:GetDistribution",
                "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution",
                "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudfront::<ACCOUNT_ID>:distribution/<DISTRIBUTION_ID>
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: May God bless your soul for this and if you believe in Heaven, I hope you'll get there!

Answer (score 1):

`aws cloudfront get-distribution-config` Generates extra information you cannot use in `update-distribution`
so you have to get only `DistributionConfig` from generated json and modify it.
using jq

```sh
aws cloudfront get-distribution --id <CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID> | jq .Distribution.DistributionConfig > config.json
```

also you will need Etag separately you can get it by:

```
ETAG=`aws cloudfront get-distribution --id <CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID> | jq -r .ETag`
```

and then use it in `update-distribution`. e.g.
if you saved config in `config.json`:

```
aws cloudfront update-distribution --id <CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID> --distribution-config "file://config.json" --if-match $ETAG > /dev/null
```

Example bash script to change Origin:
https://gist.github.com/ahmed-abdelazim/d5aa4dea6ecb5dbbff94ce1f5c1f32ff?fbclid=IwAR1QL1CujiCEyd5cDLoEuocOuXNfstxV9Ev6ndO9IorHVsx0EMroBVnimNg

```sh
#!/bin/bash
CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID=E2C3RNL2F4MRMQ
NEW_ORIGIN="origin2-zaid.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
ETAG=`aws cloudfront get-distribution --id $CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID | jq -r .ETag`
aws cloudfront get-distribution --id $CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID | \
jq --arg NEW_ORIGIN "$NEW_ORIGIN" '.Distribution.DistributionConfig.Origins.Items[0].Id=$NEW_ORIGIN' | \
jq --arg NEW_ORIGIN "$NEW_ORIGIN" '.Distribution.DistributionConfig.Origins.Items[0].DomainName=$NEW_ORIGIN' | \
jq --arg NEW_ORIGIN "$NEW_ORIGIN" '.Distribution.DistributionConfig.DefaultCacheBehavior.TargetOriginId=$NEW_ORIGIN' | \
jq .Distribution.DistributionConfig > config.json
aws cloudfront update-distribution --id $CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID --distribution-config "file://config.json" --if-match $ETAG > /dev/null
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths "/*"
rm config.json
```